# Is it possible for the Scala compiler to understand overridden Abstract Types

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, jackson, abstract

Context:

I am attempting to make use of polymorphic sub-typing provided by Jackson, JsonSubTypes, in RESTful endpoint. There is some commonality between the various request bodies so I have:

```
abstract class A extends Translatable {
  val infoA: String
  val infoB: String
}

case class B(
  infoA: String,
  infoB: String,
  infoC: String,
  infoD: Int
) extends A {
  override type T = B
  def translate(
    requestInfo: String,
    request: B
  ): String = s"<$infoA,$infoB>:$infoC-${infoD.toString}"
}


case class C(
  infoA: String,
  infoB: String,
  infoC: Array[String]
) extends A {
  override type T = C
  def translate(
    requestInfo: String,
    request: C
  ): String = s"<$infoA,$infoB>:${infoC.mkString}"
}
```

with the following trait so that without having to pattern match the incoming `A` request to either `B` or `C`:

```
trait Translatable {
  type T <: A
  def translate(
    requestInfo: String,
    request: T
  ): String
}
```

the problem is when I compile it complains about type mismatch:

```
found: request.type (with underlying type com.program.A)
required: request.T
```

I've tried a few things, to no avail, with only this seeming to get close:

- implicit generalized type constraints

```
e.g.,
def translate[X](
  requestInfo: String,
  request: X
)(implicit ev: X <:< A) = ...
(modifying the case class impl. of ^ accordingly)
```

but this leads to

> Cannot prove that com.program.A <:< request.T

Any thoughts on how to do this? Or must I just suffer the pattern match? I say because the first code block works iff I pattern match and call the concrete impl. of `translate` for either `B` or `C`, but I'd prefer to just have an `A` type param and call `translate` on it. Is that possible?

EDIT: Adding instances where the above produces compilation errors:

```
class Program {
  def doWork(
    info: String,
    request: A
  ): String = {
    request.translate(
      info,
      request // compilation fails/complains about this param in both cases
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT2: Adding qualification: I need the types to be overridden in the sub-types, `B` & `C`, so that in the translate func. I can call fields specific to `B` or `C`

Comment: "when I compile it complains about type mismatch" Compile what? Could you be more specific which particular line produces the error? The following code compiles without errors: https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/eb059348c416dead20d7af7a47acfccd

Comment: Have the same result as @DmytroMitin

Comment: My apologies, have updated w/ example

Comment: Updated `B` and `C` above w/ actual impl. of translate to highlight why I need to override the type T. I need to be able to access fields specific to the sub-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add type parameter with refined upper bound

```
def doWork[T0 <: A { type T = T0 }](
            info: String,
            request: T0
          ): String = {
  request.translate(
    info,
    request
  )
}

doWork("info1", B("infoA1", "infoB1", "infoC1", 1))//<infoA1,infoB1>:infoC1-1
doWork("info2", C("infoA2", "infoB2", Array("infoC21", "infoC22")))//<infoA2,infoB2>:infoC21infoC22
```

Comment: Bob's your uncle! Structural types! I'll have to read more about these.
This does compile, though with a Scala style complaint but I can deal with that. Thanks!

Comment: @Mastergreek more precisely, refined types.